# Why did my bash prompt turn to gibberish after I accidentally ran `cat` on a .coverage file?

Tags: bash, cat

I had just installed [coverage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage) and run it a few times when I noticed a `.coverage` file hanging around in my repo, which is -- according to the `file` utility -- a `8086 relocatable (Microsoft)` file. And then I did this, because I had no idea what it was and wanted to know what was inside it...

```
~/repos/personalsite(master 7↑)$ cat .coverage
...lots of output...
≤☃─☃┼±@≤⎽☃└:·/⎼e⎻⎺⎽/≤☃─☃┼±⎽☃└↓c⎺└/≤☃─☃┼±⎽☃└(└▒⎽├e⎼ 7↑)$
```

Even when I pressed Enter a couple times it remained like that. Not only that, when I typed into the command line, characters that I didn't expect showed up, e.g.

```
$ ↓┘ ┼⎺├ ⎺┼┌≤ ├▒▒├┬▒≤ ☃⎽ ├▒e⎼e ┼⎺├
```

The only solution was for me to close the (tmux) window. I'm just wondering (a) why this happened, and (b) if there's any way to fix this next time I happen to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question a): this depends on which type of terminal you have. Just do a `echo $TERM` to see which type of terminal you have. `xterm` should be fine. I had this problem a lot when connecting via serial console and the only working type of terminal was `vt100` (an old but very compatible terminal). Also when changing `$TERM` to `vt100` via SSH I had the same problem.

for question b): executing the command `reset` should do the trick. Maybe you see the command also in gibberish but it should work.

Just for clarification: this happens every time you try to do `cat` on a binary encoded file, not specially `.coverage` files.

Comment: Or use `stty sane`.

Comment: Using "reset" fixed the issue on a Check Point firewall console from expert mode. THANK YOU noggerl!

Answer (score 1):

The literal character `^N` can cause this behavior on certain terminals when printed. `cat` printed that character when trying to read the binary encoded file.

To reproduce this behavior, you can write the `^N` character to a file using literal character entry in `vi`. Open `vi`, enter <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-n</kbd> in insert mode, and save the file. If you `cat` this file, your terminal's encoding will be borked.

The literal character `^O` reverses this behavior, and can be written in `vi` by entering <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried to `diff` two `.vimrc` files and got into this state.  Typing `Ctrl-v` `Ctrl-o` `Enter` on the command line fixed it.  Wow.  (`reset` also fixed it, but I prefer this solution).